# LinkedIn's shareArticle Dialog Window Bug

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm hoping to connect with someone from LinkedIn or someone that is familiar with their http://linkedin.com/shareArticle popup.

I've added a "Share on LinkedIn" button on my website that uses LinkedIn's [shareArticle parameterized URL](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) to create a share popup dialog. I'm supplying OpenGraph parameters in my `<head>` to specify title, description, and image. On my live site, the image I'm providing (`og:image`) seems to be disregarded. I assumed this was because my image was smaller than minimum dimension specifications (1200x627px), but when I cloned my site to my staging server, the shareArticle link works perfectly and displays the image I want to display. The pages are identical, **so why are the first/main image in the shareArticle pop-ups different for these two pages?**

**[Live Site »](https://blogs.constellation.com/customers-community/constellation-community-roundup/)** (showing incorrect image when clicking on 'Share on LinkedIn')

**[Staging Site »](https://constellationm.staging.wpengine.com/customers-community/constellation-community-roundup/)** (showing correct image when clicking on 'Share on LinkedIn')

I should mention that I am aware that the pages are cached for 7 days, however this issue persists on new posts that are created as well.

On a side note, it seems there are differing minimum requirements for the `og:image` dimensions that LinkedIn is crawling. On this [developer doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin), LI states that the min dimensions are 80x150px, but on this [help doc](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) LI states that it's 1200x627px.